# PHP Forced file download failing in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, content-type

I have a site where I'm using the following code to force a file download via PHP:

```
$ZipData = file_get_contents($zipFilename);
$ZipSize = filesize($zipFilename);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$ZipTitle.".zip");
echo $ZipData;
```

While this works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, it simply does nothing in Internet Explorer. While Googling I found a potential solution and changed the code to as follows:

```
$ZipData = file_get_contents($zipFilename);
$ZipSize = filesize($zipFilename);
if (strstr($HTTP_USER_AGENT,"MSIE")){
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-type: application-download");
    header("Content-Length: $ZipSize");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$ZipTitle.".zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}else{
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$ZipTitle.".zip");
}
echo $ZipData;
```

But still no luck. I don't know why it's failing, nor where to start looking for errors or problems, is this just some I.E. bug I'm unaware of? Where should I start trying to find a solution?

Note: $ZipTitle will always be 'TexturePacker_Pack_xxx' where xxx is an incremented number. $ZipFilename is an existing zip file which is unlinked AFTER the file is sent to the browser.

Edit: The site and code in question are in action on http://www.texturepacker.net

Comment: Where are you defining `ZipSize` in the second solution?

Comment: Following Code Igniter's helper you should try with `Content-Type: application/x-zip`

Comment: `application-download` is an even more invalid MIME type. Also enclose the filename header property with single quotes. Try disallowing range requests with `Accept-Ranges: none`.

Comment: Defining ZipSize the same in both examples.
Tried application/x-zip, application/application-download and application/forced-download, none changed the result.

Also tried using Accept-Ranges: none and header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='".$ZipTitle.".zip'"); and both make no perceivable difference.

Comment: Have you tried `Cache-Control: private` already?

Comment: Just tried Cache-Control: private, no change.

Comment: Can't edit my answer, but I've been doing more research on this. If your server is sending the file with gzip enabled, IE will think the zip file is corrupted. Add `apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');` in your PHP download file before the actual download. That, and fix your `header("Content-type: application-download")` to read instead as `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content-Length` header seems to be incorrect. PHP `filesize` [expects a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and returns an int.

Change it to actually get the size of the file on disk:

```
$zipFile = "C:\ZipFile.zip";  
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($ZipFile));
```

Comment: That's exactly what it is set to (provided it's the same in code #2 as code #1).

Comment: That's currently what's being used for $ZipSize as per the code.